# Create different version of swf file for each release build in flash builder

Tags: apache-flex, build, flash, version

Recently, i have faced an issue of caching of my flex swf file on client's ie-explorer machine and i could not tell him every time, delete all your cache data and reopen the browser.

so, finally, i have think to make the different version of swf file for each release build and give it to client while production release.

Could you please have any idea about handling/maintain version of release swf file in flash builder.

i am using the flash builder 4.0 and using flex 4 in my application.

Comment: @dain sorry i am new in stackoverflow .plz explain ur previous comment

Comment: No worries, so in order to help other people who have the same problem as you, once you get an answer which helped you to solve it, please click on the little tick next to the answer to mark it as the solution. You can click on your own username to see your profile with your questions and go back to your older questions to do this.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should do this versioning in the deployment process, ie when you upload the new SWF to your webserver, as the HTML / JS embedding needs to be updated too anyway.

Comment: Not in deployment process but it could handle in build bundle process but i am finding different or easy solution

Comment: I don't think FB can do this out of the box, but you can use Ant scripting to create your own deployment process.